# Solving the ODE $(4xy + 2x^2 + 3y^4)dx + (2x^2+5xy^3)dy = 0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The monster is $$(4xy + 2x + 3y^4)dx + (2x^2+5xy^3)dy = 0 $$
I tried all the standard methods and i tried $y=z^a$ and $dy=az^{a-1}dz$.

and i get
$$(4z^ax + 2x + 3z^{4a})dx + (2az^{a-1} + 5az^{4a-1})dz =0$$
but doesn't make sense $a-1+1=4a-1+1$
I don't need the exact answer, only some bibliography of these kind of ODE's
[image: a]
This is the list of exerscise if someone recognice the book

Comment: You have both $dx$, $dy$, and an equation of the form $f(x,y)dx+g(x,y)dy=0$. What does that tell you? Did you check whether the function is exact, or if you can make it exact?

Comment: Do you know how to solve exact equations?

Comment: This question should have had $2x^2$instead of $2x$, I have corrected seeing the attachment of OP..

Comment: You wrote "I tried all the standard methods" but, what's "all" here? Is the problem well-write? If the answer is "yes", so you should to notice that the ODE is non linear of first order. Maybe you can write the ODE as $M(x,y)\, {\rm d}x+N(x,y)\, {\rm d}y=0$ and then testing if $M_{y}=N_{x}$. If the answer is "no" so maybe an integrating factor of the form $(x+y)^{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha\in \mathbf{R}$.

Comment: @Z Ahmed no it is $2x$ (equation 15 in the attachment). And in the title, both $2x^2$ have to be replaced also by $2x.$

Comment: @ZAhmed sorry, my comment did'n reach you because I didn't type the notification correctly. Meanwhile, there was an answer below (see the comments).

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are trying to solve Eq.$(17)$ from the joint list. This equation is :
$$(4xy + 3y^4)dx + (2x^2+5xy^3)dy = 0 $$
This is not the equation you wrote :
$$(4xy + 2x + 3y^4)dx + (2x^2+5xy^3)dy = 0 $$
The term $2x$ is superfluous. Without it the integrating factor is easy to find. I let that for you. The solution is :
$$\boxed{x^3y^5+x^4y^2=\text{constant}}$$
With the extra term $2x$ it seems that the solution cannot be expressed with a finite number of standard functions. One have to a use numerical method of solving ( with specified boundary condition ).

Comment: As pointed in my comment 1 hour ago, the original OP was not $(4xy + 2x + 3y^4)dx + (2x^2+5xy^3)dy = 0$ but $$(4xy + 2x + 3y^4)dx + (2x+5xy^3)dy = 0,$$ which is eqn 15 and not 17. https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4533723/revisions

Comment: All this makes the question muddled and the OP doesn't correct it. I vote to close the question.